# Pandas use outer join and group by to fill in missing dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is my data frame

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample data
data = {'store name': ['Store A', 'Store A', 'Store B', 'Store B', 'Store C', 'Store C'],
        'time': ['2023-04-25 00:00:00', '2023-04-25 01:00:00', '2023-04-25 00:00:00', '2023-04-25 01:00:00', '2023-04-25 00:00:00', '2023-04-25 01:00:00'],
        'sales': [100, 200, 150, 250, 300, 350]}

# create pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to fill in missing hours for all stores for 04-25

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 25)
end = datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 26)
full_range = pd.date_range(start, end, freq = 'H')
time = pd.DataFrame(full_range, columns = ['time'])
df = df.groupby('store name').apply(lambda x : pd.merge(x, time, on = 'time', how = 'outer')).reset_index()
```

However this will return that 'store name' already exists as a column. If I do reset_index(drop = True) then it will get rid of all the added missing time. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `pivot` or `pivot_table` to reshape your dataframe then reindex the `time`:

```
start = pd.Timestamp(2023, 4, 25)
end = pd.Timestamp(2023, 4, 26)
full_range = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='H', name='time')

out = (df.pivot(index='time', columns='store name', values='sales')
         .reindex(full_range, fill_value=0).unstack().rename('sales').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   store name                time  sales
0     Store A 2023-04-25 00:00:00    100
1     Store A 2023-04-25 01:00:00    200
2     Store A 2023-04-25 02:00:00      0
3     Store A 2023-04-25 03:00:00      0
4     Store A 2023-04-25 04:00:00      0
..        ...                 ...    ...
70    Store C 2023-04-25 20:00:00      0
71    Store C 2023-04-25 21:00:00      0
72    Store C 2023-04-25 22:00:00      0
73    Store C 2023-04-25 23:00:00      0
74    Store C 2023-04-26 00:00:00      0
```

**Update**

> What if my values are of multiple columns like ['sales', 'traffic']

For multiple value columns, you can use:

```
out = (df.pivot(index='time', columns='store name', values=['sales', 'traffic'])
         .reindex(full_range, fill_value=0).stack(level=1)
         .swaplevel().sort_index(level='store name').reset_index())
```

Comment: What if my values are of multiple columns like ['sales', 'traffic']

Comment: I updated my answer according your request. Can you check it please?